# Kotlin Basics: print same string more than twice

Tags: logging, kotlin

So I recently started with Kotlin and ran into a very basic but yet crazy behavior: Whenever I want to repeat a `println` more than twice, I only get the first two `println`s executed. Let me explain:

```
fun helloWorld() { 
   println("Hello World!")
   println("Hello World!")
   println("Hello World!")
}
```

just prints

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

in the Logcat. So it doesn't execute the last statement. But adding a number like

```
fun helloWorld() { 
   println("Hello World! 1")
   println("Hello World! 2")
   println("Hello World! 3")
}
```

prints

```
Hello World! 1
Hello World! 2
Hello World! 3
```

as expected. So as I see it, every identical operation is only executed twice?! This is driving me insane. Where's my error?

Comment: It is impossible

Comment: Simply impossible

Comment: It's most likely that Logcat simply ignores repeating messages. By appending the line number, the lines are no longer identical and so all of them are shown.

Answer (score 1):

So @pappbence96 pointed me in the right direction. This is in fact a 'feature' of Logcat. Repetitive messages will be ignored!? See here for more info:
[Reddit: Logcat now hides repetitive messages](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8ckqdr/psa_logcat_now_hides_repetitive_messages/)